# Shinyapp: How to avoid overcharge on paid account

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I just paid for a yearly starter plan on Shinyapps.io and noticed that I will get overcharged if I exceed the active monthly hours (100h). I am very worried because a lot of people may use my app and will likely exceed that amount. Is there a way to avoid getting overcharged, and for instance set the app so it will just not be available to users again until the following month cycle (as for Free accounts)?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest contacting their support team directly.